# Removing radio button from row data control

Tags: flask

I have a form with a table inside which shows the results of a database query. That table has a radio control and two buttons: one for edit, another for delete. In order for me to modify a row, I have to select the radio of the corresponding row and then press either "delete" or "edit" button. What I want to do is to remove that radio button and make the buttons take me straight to editing the corresponding row. When I remove the radio button (it's kind of obvious) every buttom from every row only  take me to edit/delete the first result.

This is my form:

```
<form method="POST" id="form2" action="{{ url_for('edit_or_delete') }}">

        <table class="table" id="tableSelect">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Manejar</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Concepto</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Updated</th>
            </tr>

            <!-- loop for results -->
            {% for s in mov %}
            <tr><label for="id"></label>
                <td class="center-align"><input type="radio" name="id" value="{{ s.id }}" required></td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" name="choice" value="delete" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="choice" value="edit" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button>
                </td>
                <td>${{ s.cantidad }}</td>
                <td>{{ s.concepto }}</td>
                <td>{{ s.fecha }}</td>
                <td>{{ s.udpated }}</td></label>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
<!-- end form-group -->
        </form>
```

This is my route:

```
@app.route('/edit_or_delete', methods=['POST'])
def edit_or_delete():
    id = request.form['id']
    choice = request.form['choice']
    movs = Movs.query.filter(Movs.id == id).first()
    # two forms in this template
    form1 = AddRecord()
    form2 = DeleteForm()
    return render_template('edit_or_delete.html', movs=movs, form1=form1, form2=form2, choice=choice)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a route that displays the results of the database query in a table:

```
@app.route('/some_route')
def some_route():
    result = Some_Database_Class.query.all()
    return render_template('list.html', result=result)
```

list.html would look something like this:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Some Data</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    {% for row in result %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row.some_data }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ url_for('edit_row', row_id=row.id }}">
                This links to an edit route with the row id included in the URL
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="delete_row" data-row-id="{{ row.id }}">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

When making an edit we redirect the user to a route which takes a parameter <row_id>, loads the corresponding row and displays all the necessary information in a form.

```
@app.route('/edit_row/<row_id>'), methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_row(row_id):
    row = Some_Database_Class.query.filter_by(id=row_id).first()
    form = EditRowForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form.some_form_field.data = row.some_data
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        row.some_data = form.some_form_field.data
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template('edit_row.html', form=form)
```

When deleting a row you could do the same, but then you would have a GET request deleting something on the server, which shouldn't happen. You can easily use jQuery to send a DELETE request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Delete a row on button click
    $('.delete_row').click(function () {
        var row_id = $(this).attr('data-row-id')
        var ajaxReq = $.ajax({
            url: '/delete_row/' + row_id,
            type: 'DELETE',
            statusCode: {
                200: function () {
                    window.location.reload()
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

When the user now clicks the delete button a request now gets sent to a route that would look like this:

```
@app.route('/delete_row/<row_id>'), methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_row(row_id):
    row = Some_Database_Class.query.filter_by(id=row_id).first()
    if row is not None:
        db.session.delete(row)
        db.session.commit()
        return Response(status=200)
    return Response(status=404)
```

If the row is found it gets deleted and the window gets reloaded for the user.

I don't know if this is the standard or best way to do it, but it works for me.

Comment: Genius! Thank you so much!